# Where to add the JavaScript SDK code in the page.php of my WordPress theme for the Facebook Plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook

I'm not sure where to add the code that Facebook provided for the Facebook Plugin, to my *page.php*.

This is my original *page.php*:

```
<?php 
/**
* Theme Page Section for our theme.
*
* @package ThemeGrill
* @subpackage Spacious
* @since Spacious 1.0
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php do_action( 'spacious_before_body_content' ); ?>

<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" class="clearfix">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

            <?php
            do_action( 'spacious_before_comments_template' );
// If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
            if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
                comments_template();                    
            do_action ( 'spacious_after_comments_template' );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php spacious_sidebar_select(); ?>

<?php do_action( 'spacious_after_body_content' ); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is the **Facebook Plugin Code**:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
```

I asked the support of the theme where to insert the Facebook Plugin Code, and they replied this:

> Right after body tab we have included a action hook: do_action( 'before' );
>   Create a function in your child theme, add the required code and hook it to above action hook.
>   Something like this:
>   function any_name() {
>   paste your code here (if it is HTML then make proper use of start/end of php tag)
>   }
>   add_action( 'before', 'any_name' );

I don't see any *body* tab.

Is it correct if I instert the Facebook Plugin Code just under the line?

```
<?php do_action( 'spacious_before_body_content' ); ?>
```

So it will looks like this:

```
<?php 
/**
* Theme Page Section for our theme.
*
* @package ThemeGrill
* @subpackage Spacious
* @since Spacious 1.0
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php do_action( 'spacious_before_body_content' ); ?>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
            (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>

<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" class="clearfix">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

            <?php
            do_action( 'spacious_before_comments_template' );
// If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
            if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
                comments_template();                    
            do_action ( 'spacious_after_comments_template' );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php spacious_sidebar_select(); ?>

<?php do_action( 'spacious_after_body_content' ); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If you can provide also a brief explanation or link where I can read about the how and the why, if would be a good chance for me to learn something new.

**edit_1:**
[THIS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) is the plugin I'd like to insert to a page in my website. It will be added in the "thank you page" after subscribing the Newsletter. You can try to set it up and do "Get Code" so you'll see what it says.

In order to add the plugin to your website, you have to add 2 codes:

1. the JavaScript SDK code (above called **Facebook Plugin Code**): you have to add it somewhere in a .php file to connect your website to your facebook page;
2. the actual code to show the content: you'll have to put this code where you want the plugin to appear, as in a post, in a page or in the sidebar.

What I noticed is, if I add the first code (the JavaScript SDK) into the file page.php, I can only add the second code (the one that shows the content) into a page (and not for example in the sidebar). If I add the first code into header.php, I'll be able to add the second code everywhere.

The problem is, I don't know how to add the first code and where. I mean, fisically I don't know where to start writing the code into the .php file.

**edit_2:**
Ok, here an exerpt of my header, should I paste the code in the SPACE ONE, SPACE TWO or somewhere else?

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
--SPACE ONE--
<?php   do_action( 'before' ); ?>
--SPACE TWO--
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <?php do_action( 'spacious_before_header' ); ?>
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header clearfix">
    </header>
```

About the hook, you are right, it confused me a lot!Ahah!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when you add Facebook Script on any page, you just need to place the code snippet right after the body tag. The wordpress page will be added inside the body tag, so What you are doing above will work just fine.

> Right after body tab we have included a action hook: do_action( 'before' ); Create a function in your child theme, add the required code and hook it to above action hook. Something like this: function any_name() { paste your code here (if it is HTML then make proper use of start/end of php tag) } add_action( 'before', 'any_name' );

But what's being mentioned here is a better way to do this.. You need to create a hook for your facebook script. This way, you will only need to call the Action and not copy the snippet every time you add it on each page.

For more information, please check the Facebook SDK Documentation.

> The fb-root element must not be hidden using display: none or visibility: hidden, or some parts of the SDK will not work properly in Internet Explorer.
>
> The SDK inserts elements into fb-root which expect to be positioned relative to the body or relative to an element close to the top of the page. It is best if the fb-root element is not inside of an element with position: absolute or position: relative. If you must place the fb-root element inside of a positioned element, then you should also give it a position close to the top of the body or some parts of the SDK may not work properly.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not a programmer and I don't understand what you are saying. I already read the [FB SDK Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) but I didn't find anything that can help me. 

Facebook is telling me to add the code mentioned above named **Facebook Plugin Code** into the file **page.php**. Actually, I can add it in the **header.php** instead. The problem is, I don't know where.

I tried to search how to make a hook, but couldn't find any easy guide to follow to create this hook. I just want to add the code to my child theme on WordPress.

Comment: Ow.. Facebook plugins already have codes ready for integration. And it will work on Wordpress pages.. By the way what facebook plugin are you trying to add? and which pages do you want that plug-in to be added?

Comment: please see the edit_1 at the bottom of the first post @severinolorillajr

Comment: well, you can add the javascript code (1st part) in header.php,paste that right after the opening `<body>` tag. Then on your templates where you want to add the plugin (like thank you page, just add the html (2nd part). That's it! Don't bother adding the hooks and wordpress actions, it will just confuse you. :)

Comment: please see the edit_2 at the bottom of the first post and thank you for your help @severinolorillajr

Comment: Though both will do just fine, Space One is better. After adding the script on header, feel free to add the html code snippet that shows the actual content on any of your templates.. Your welcome @Alessio!